# Android free app with in-app billing not available in China, Serbia and Taiwan

Tags: android, google-play

I just published an app on Google Play, and I've noticed that it is not available in China, Serbia and Taiwan(on the Pricing and Distribution tab checkboxes next to these countries names are disabled and the names are strikethrough). My app is free but it uses in-app billing. So in all logic it should be available in these countries. If not, then I don't understand what I did wrong and how come apps like Shellrazer and Temple Run are available in these countries and they both are free and they are using in-app billing?

Comment: Maybe in-app billing is not supported in those countries?  If that's the case, then your app will not be available there.

Comment: Yes, in-app billing is not supported in those countries. But like I've said, Shellrazer, Temple Run and many other free apps that have in-app billing are available in those countries.

Comment: But are you sure it's exactly the same app?  Maybe it's a different app with the same name that's specifically done for those countries and doesn't have in-app billing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I do think that there is only one build(with in-app billing) for all countries. I guess I could ask the creators of those apps how they managed to publish their respective apps in all countries.

Comment: Hello, I am facing the same issue.
Did you have any chance to get answers from those publishers ?

Comment: @devMatt Hi, yes the creators of Shellrazer replied to my email. They told they have no idea how users in China, Serbia and Taiwan can download their application, because on Shellrazer's Pricing and Distribution tab checkboxes next to these countries names are disabled and the names are strikethrough(the same as with my app). So all in all, I have no idea what's going on and how is this possible. Cheers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about policies / SLA's of a service provider, see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Google Play Team:

> "Please note that applications with in-app purchases fall under paid
>   category."
>
> Since both of your apps have in-app items they are treated as paid
>   apps and some locations are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons why your app isn't available in those areas.

As previously stated, the reason why your app isn't available in Serbia and Taiwan is that apps with in-app purchases count as paid category and some regions don't support these types of apps.

The reason why your app isn't available in China is that Google Play is blocked.